# Is sending the same mesage twice a good policy against UDPs disadvantages?

Tags: c#, udpclient

I have c# executables called server, client and client2 messaging each other on the same addr. I am differentiating the msgs  by port number at which they are coming.

regular run-1
Server starts
client joins, leaves

run-2
server starts
client 2 joins, leaves

run-3
server starts
client joins
client2 joins (here comes the problem), sometimes it gets the reply from server, sometimes it just hangs and the reply from server doesnt reach.

I am using the UDPClient blocking msg transfer routines.

**current solution: I am sending the same msg from server twice(in hope of atleast getting the second time around), as it is very important, and I am no longer losing this msg. What can be potential downfall of such a temporary hack?**

Also please tell me if my q? is incomplete I ll provide more details.

Comment: You are asking how reliable is an inherently unreliable protocol? Why not use TCP, like God intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP itself is unreliable. You can write your own code to make it reliable for your needs, however it's up to you to do that. If you want a reliable stream, use TCP.

Sending a UDP packet twice may reduce problems with packet loss, however you have no guarantee. I suggest you implement some acknowledgement system where the clients send a packet back to the server when they've successfully processed an incoming packet. The server repeatedly sends the original packet until it sees the acknowledgement. (You should still have some limit on this, otherwise it'll try forever)

A situation where UDP is useful is where you don't mind the occasional lost packet, but need the reduced latency that UDP can bring (as there are no built-in re-transmits). For instance state information for games, where the server sends game data via UDP. If a client doesn't receive a packet, it'll catch up when the next one arrives in a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

In a short answer, UDP is *not* reliable. The very definition of UDP is that there is no way of telling, let alone assuring, whether a packet will reach its destination.

If these messages are as important as you lead on, I recommend using TCP instead. This way, transmission errors and failures are automatically handled for you and you can be assured the packet will reach its destination.

As for the potential downfall of your hack, you have to handle the case of both copies of the message arriving, as well as not accounting for the case of where neither copy arrives. To me, trying to reinvent the wheel (sending acknowledgement messages, retrying when timed out, handling duplicate receipts) is not worth the effort in this case. Just use TCP.

Answer (score 2):

Use TCP if reliability trumps everything. But if you need low latency and packet-based comm, then you can stick with UDP but implement a better retransmission process.

For example in SIP (VOIP protocol), it is generally recommended to do the following:

1. Set up a timer to fire at 500 ms (T1).
2. Send the request and start the timer.
3. If T1 has expired without getting a response, retransmit the request and double T1.
4. Perform #3 until you get a response or until T1 reaches 32 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

UDP is as reliable as the lower levels in the network stack allow; IP is fundamentally a best-effort service. What this means is that your data won't be intentionally lost or corrupted, but that no guarantees are made. The good news is that, under what are probably usual circumstances, the inherent reliability of the channel is pretty good, so UDP does OK. Let's say each UDP datagram has a probability p of reaching the receiver undamaged. In this case, the probability of at least one of N packets making it to the receiver undamaged is 1-(1-p)^N. For high p (greater than 90%), this converges pretty quickly to 1. However, there's always a chance data will be corrupted in all N packets.

You can build reliability guarantees into the protocol at the transport layer; in a sense, TCP is just UDP with this (and other) extra implementation already performed. Many CS networking courses involve developing a reliable UDP protocol. The benefits here are clear: you get certain (as opposed to very likely, statistically speaking) reliability (assuming you do it right).

To go into too much more detail would be to open a can of worms many authors have written extensively about. If you'd like to learn more, I can try to recommend some reading.